# django - syntax error views.py - three dots (...) - what code goes there?

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie going over the django tutorial.
In part 4 - Generic Views I am stuck with views.py

The suggested code for replacing the old one is:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
     template_name = 'polls/index.html'
     context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    ... # same as above
```

I am getting a syntax error for the 'three dots' and do not know what "same as above" is refering to (what code goes there?).

Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation of the `vote()` view which is exists in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form) above the code from your question:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the same code as [in the first section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form) of this part of the tutorial.

The tutorial presumes that you go through it step by step and thus you already have the code for `vote` function in place when you reach this step.

As follows:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```